# ProFTPd overwrite directory setting when globbing

Tags: wildcards, proftpd

I have lots of folders and I want to apply some settings (hide files) to almost all of them, but there are 2 folders where I want different settings.

proftpd.conf:

```
<Directory /shared/A/>
  HideFiles none
  <Limit ALL>
    IgnoreHidden Off
  </Limit>
</Directory>

<Directory /shared/B/>
  HideFiles none
  <Limit ALL>
    IgnoreHidden Off
  </Limit>
</Directory>


<Directory /shared/*/>
  HideFiles "(private|\\.htaccess)$"
  <Limit ALL>
    IgnoreHidden On
  </Limit>
</Directory>

<Directory /shared/*/*/>
  HideFiles none
  <Limit ALL>
    IgnoreHidden Off
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

/shared/A and /shared/B still hiding "private" folder and ".htaccess".

How to hide them in all folders, except "A" and "B"? I want to hide it only in /shared/*/, not apply inheritance.